# rounded shoulders in planks

Tags: squats, shoulders, home-exercise, performance, planks

Recently , I record my self doing planks and squats. After I was supposing I am doing them right,  I detect that:

during planks: my sholders are directed down and they are  making  my upper back  to appear like a mountain and I dont know what to do with my head

During squats:  my upper body is shifted forward and  it is rounded

I  am not able to go to gym due to my work time, I work  from  8 am  till 8 pm, so usually I do my workout at moring (6 am). So I have no coach to help me fix this.

Can some one here help me?   what should i do to make my plank in the correct form? what muscle should be strengthened so that  I get rid of the rounded shoulders.

Note : I find this answer on this answer on this website, [Plank Progressions](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/18989/plank-progression/28024#28024),  I am not sure it is sufficient for  me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing to be concerned with, that’s a normal compensation while doing planks.  A couple things are going on here:

- When you raise your glutes, your shoulders begin to point downward as
  you're moving your center of mass forward.  The more weight loaded on
  your forearms the less work your core has to do.

  [image]
- This also results in scapular protraction.  A motion that should be
  stabilized *(or minimized)* during this exercise.

---

**A simple fix for this:**

1. Do planks parallel to a mirror *(provides visual feedback allowing you to self correct)*
2. Focus on keeping your shoulder blades together *(scapular retraction)* and keeping your glutes in line with your body.

---

**Areas of Focus:**

1. **Proprioception** - which is the awareness of your body's position in space – the mirror will help correct this.
2. **Scapula Retractors Strengthening** - Rhomboids Major and Lower Trapezius

---

For squats ideally I'd have a friend or someone with experience teach you.  Try to keep your back straight while:

[image]

1. Holding a Wooden Stick or a Lightly Padded Weighted Bar and Practice Lowering your body keeping your back straight
2. Add a tactile cue (such as a plyo box or some object that you squat and try to touch each time you go down.

There's a lot more going on with squats (foot position etc) so I'd really try and find some in person help.

> **Want to see someone do a perfect squat?**  
> Look at any child --
>   seriously 
>   *(faulty **functional** movement patterns are learned)*

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer,  just  I would like to ask you about the sticj=k I hold during squat, should I hold it in front  or back of my head?

Comment: Running vertically running on top of your spine - should give you a better idea what proper form feels like.  See this also

https://www.builtlean.com/2011/12/22/how-to-increase-squat-depth/